# getting a issue with converting string to float with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

so i trying to replace col with a string but everytime i do that it trying to convert the string to a float then it wont place it but when you .astype(string) it does not work. i am stuck also when i try this on another computer it works fine aswhile.

```
import shutil
import pandas as pd
from art import *
from time import sleep

templet_step1 = "SIPStep1.csv"
templet_step2 = "SIPStep2.csv"
templet_step1_moved = "done_import_file\SIPStep1.csv"
templet_step2_moved = "done_import_file\SIPStep2.csv"
master_new_hire_excel = "Master New Hire Excel Doc.xlsx"

db1 = pd.read_excel(master_new_hire_excel, sheet_name="SIP Import S1")
db2 = pd.read_excel(master_new_hire_excel, sheet_name="SIP Import S2")

list_of_col1 = "User Name", "First Name", "Last Name", "Display Name", "Extension", "DID", "Password",\
"Network ID","Mailbox", "Roles", "Workgroups", "Station Name", "OCS "


with open(templet_step1_moved, "r") as csv
    op1 = csvf1.readlines()
with open(templet_step2_moved, "r") as csv
    op2 = csvf2.readlines()

done_file = "done_import_file"
shutil.copy2(templet_step1, done_file)
shutil.copy2(templet_step2, done_file)

for i in db1.index:
    db1.at[i, "Password"] = "12345"

    if db1.loc[i, "titles"] == "Contract Review Specialist":
        db1.at[i, "Roles"] = "Business User"
        db1.at[i, "titles"] = ""
        db1.at[i, "managers"] = ""

    if db1.loc[i, "titles"] == "Customer Care Advisor":
        db1.at[i, "Workgroups"] = "CCA"
        db1.at[i, "titles"] = ""
        db1.at[i, "managers"] = ""

    else:
        db1.at[i, list_of_col1] = ""
        db1.at[i, "titles"] = ""
        db1.at[i, "managers"] = ""

db1.rename(columns={"N": '', "O": ""})

db1.to_csv(templet_step1_moved, index=False)

db1 = pd.read_csv(templet_step1_moved)
db1.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
db1 = db1.rename(columns={"titles": "", "managers": ""})
db1.to_csv(templet_step1_moved, index=False)
```

```
error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\phone_script\main.py", line 61, in <module>
    db1.at[i, "Roles"] = "Business User"
  File "C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2286, in __setitem__
    return super().__setitem__(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2237, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, value=value, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3826, in _set_value
    series._values[loc] = value
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Business User'
```

if yall having any ideas let me know. been trying to figure it out almost all day but keep getting stuck on this.

Comment: i think i fixed but updating the pandas module but not sure yet.

Comment: I don't understand, you trying to convert string to float?

Comment: Before helping with your question, can you show a sample of your `Business User` column?

Answer (score 0):

Try these two methods:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].astype(float)

df['Column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column'])
```

Comment: i can try that. let me see if that works